Contact Key Usage
I wanted to create an automated process to send out an email from Marketing Cloud to me if the number of contact keys reach 90% of the allocated Contact key Usage. Has anyone created such an automation in Marketing Cloud?
Thanks and Regards,
Suyash

You need Mobile Connect and an SQL Query; the rest is no code.
In Mobile Connect, Manage > Contacts

Go to List Tab
Create List
Filtered List
based on All Contacts
System Data > Contact > Contact Key
is not null


==
Then, in an automation, refresh the Mobile Filtered List in Step 1

Next you want your data in a DE so you can run verification activities
Mobile Filtered lists can be used in SQL; source e.g.: Query MobileConnect Lists
Step 2 in your automation is an sql
SELECT
subscriberKey
From
yourMobileFilteredList
/* overwrite into someOtherDE*/

Step 3 is a Verification step on someOtherDE, that counts if the amount of records is above (your desired number)

Schedule the automation and you should be done.

I personally prefer running Contacts Count report on a weekly basis, and use its output to determine the current count, and trigger an email if it exceeds a set threshold. I have described the process here
